# Class "App\Models\... not found in controller

Tags: model, controller, namespaces, laravel-8

I am pulling my hair off... I have many controllers/models all working fine but not this one... getting error:

```
 Class "App\Models\SC_LogTranslation" not found
```

in Sc_tablesController

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Models\SC_LogTranslation;

 class Sc_tablesController
 {
      public function index(Request $request)
      {
      ...
      $records = SC_LogTranslation::...
            ->whereRaw($table->whereRaw)
            ->paginate($nipp);
```

Model SC_LogTranslation

```
 namespace App\Models;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
 class SC_LogTranslation extends Model
 {

      // model attributes
      protected $guarded = []; // all fields are free to be created/updated - no field is guarded
      protected $table = 'sc_logTranslations';
 
 }
```

Comment: Would `composer dump-autoload` help?

Comment: @brombeer Unfortunately not... same after php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: I found the error... the model file was missing the .php extension!